# Monotonically increasing function and supremes

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, inequality, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a monotonically increasing function  and $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ where $A \neq \emptyset$ and boundend.

i) If f is continuous function, prove that $f(\sup (A))= \sup (f(A))$

ii) Find a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ wich do not fulfilled i).

For i), I thought because $A$ is boundend it has supreme,
$$ x \le \sup A$$
In other hand, because $f$ is monotonically increasing, if $x \le \sup A$ then $f(x) \le f(\sup A)$ for $x \in A$.

As $f$ is continuous and monotonically  increasing in a boundend set, the set $f(A)$ has a supreme, i.e $f(y) \le \sup f(A)$ for $y \in A$, so $\sup f(A)$ and $f(\sup A)$ are upper bounds.

But I don't know what else I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(x)\leq f(\sup A)$ for all $x\in A$, we should get $$\sup(f(A))\leq f(\sup A).$$ For $\sup A$, you can find an increasing sequence $(a_n)\subseteq A$ converging to $\sup A$. Clearly, for each $n$, we have $$f(a_n)\leq\sup(f(A)).$$ Since $f$ is continuous, the function values $f(a_n)\to f(\sup A)$ and thus $$f(\sup A)\leq\sup(f(A)).$$

Answer (score 2):

This is about second one.

Consider the function $f$ which is defined as $f(x) = 1$ if $x \ne 0$ and $f(0) = 0$ and $A=[-1,0]$. Clearly we have $sup A = 0$ and $f(sup A) = 0$. Observe that $f(A) =\{0,1\}$ whose supremum is $1$.